# Are there any libraries for converting handwriting to parseable text in Objective-C/Swift?

Tags: library, java, ios, ocr

As the title suggests, are there any open-source (or paid) libraries for Objective-C or Swift that convert handwriting to parsable text (String, array of characters, whatever)? I've seen this for Java (which I'm assuming would work for Android since it's Java), [Recommendations for Handwriting Recognition Libraries/Packages in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768664/recommendations-for-handwriting-recognition-libraries-packages-in-java), but I'd like to find something that could work either solely on iOS, or on both iOS and Android, but iOS is a must.

Thanks!

Comment: You might have a look at [Tessarect](https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS). I believe it's built for 'real' type, though, not handwriting.

Comment: @Undo: You are correct. Tessarect will not do handwriting recognition.